# Joda - change format/pattern using another DateTime object

Tags: java, jodatime

I have the following `String` representing a time.

```
7pm
```

I wish to convert it into the following format:

```
19:00
```

I have used the following approach to create a DateTime object with the original time.

```
DateTimeFormatter oldFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hha");
DateTime oldTime = oldFormat.parseDateTime("7pm");
```

Now I wish to convert it into 24 hour time like so:

```
DateTimeFormatter newFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");
DateTime formatted = newFormat.parseDateTime( << oldTime >>);
```

What can I do to achieve something similar to the last line?

Comment: A *formatted* DateTime is no longer a DateTime. It's a string. So you want `String formatted = newFormat.print(oldTime)`

Comment: And why choose DateTime? There is no date part and no timezone in 7pm. Why not use the appropriate type: LocalTime?

Comment: @Michael perfect! Feel free to add it as an answer

Comment: Any reason to use LocalTime? Performance I take

Comment: Correctness? Logic? Easier migration to java.time, which is less sloppy than joda?